# How to fix IndexError when you have tried "everything"

Tags: python

My Python web scraper gathers a lot of data and then all of the sudden stops with an IndexError. I have tried different pages and setups, but they stop at random spots.

(part of) My code is as follows

```
numListings = int(re.findall(r'\d+', numListingsRaw)[0])
numPages = math.ceil(numListings / 100)

print(numPages) 


for numb in range(1, numPages):
    pageSoup = make_soup("https://url" + str(numb) + "&pmax=5000&srt=df-a")
    containers = pageSoup.findAll("li", {"class":"occasion popup_click_event 
    aec_popup_click"})

for container in containers:

    ID = container.a["data-id"]
    titel = container["data-vrnt"].replace(",", "|")
    URL = container.a["href"]
    merk = container["data-mrk"]
    soort = container["data-mdl"]
    prijs = container.find("div", {"class":"occ_price"}).text.strip()

    ## Bouwjaar en km
    bouwjaarKM = container.span.text.strip().split(", ")
    bouwjaarRaw = bouwjaarKM[0].split(": ")
    bouwjaar = bouwjaarRaw[1]

    km_int = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, bouwjaarKM[1])))
    km = str(km_int)

    rest = container.find("div", {"class":"occ_extrainfo"}).text.strip()
    rest_split = rest.split(", ")
    brandstof = rest_split[0]
    inhoud = rest_split[1]
    vermogen = rest_split[2]
    transmissie = rest_split[3]
    carroserie = rest_split[4]
    kleur = rest_split[5]
```

This it the exact error message:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Webscraper_multi2.py", line 62, in <module>
inhoud = rest_split[1]
IndexError: list index out of range"
```

I know it has something to do with the for loop, but I cannot get my head around it.

Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: Whats the output of `print(rest_split)`?

Comment: `rest_split = rest.split(", ")` is returning a list that is shorter than you think

Comment: You need to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check length before trying to access a given index that requires the length:

```
rest = container.find("div", {"class":"occ_extrainfo"}).text.strip()
rest_split = rest.split(", ")
if len(rest_split) >= 6:
    brandstof = rest_split[0]
    inhoud = rest_split[1]
    vermogen = rest_split[2]
    transmissie = rest_split[3]
    carroserie = rest_split[4]
    kleur = rest_split[5]
```

If you know that your split list is exactly the length you want (`if len(rest_split) == 6:`), you can unpack the list in a single line:

```
brandstof, inhoud, vermogen, transmissie, carroserie, kleur = rest_split
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot. I will provide context for future reference in a separate comment.

Answer (score 0):

Print the value of `rest_split`. You will find that it is a list with length less than 2 for that is what is needed for a list to have an index 1.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. I'll explain the context in another comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the extremely fast replies! With your help I got it working.

For some context:
I was trying to scrape a 2nd hand automobile website. With the tips that I got I changed the output per item to print the rest_split list.

The list that I am trying to scrape is 7 elements long. But on the website, for some reason a motor cycle was added to the search results. This one only had 1 element, hence the error.

The solution for people that might have a similar problem:

```
rest = container.find("div", {"class":"occ_extrainfo"}).text.strip()
rest_split = rest.split(", ")
if len(rest_split) == 7:
    brandstof = rest_split[0]
    inhoud = rest_split[1]
    vermogen = rest_split[2]
    transmissie = rest_split[3]
    carroserie = rest_split[4]
    kleur = rest_split[5]
```

Special thanks to JacobIRR who actually made life so easy that I didn't even have to think about it.